# Silverlight on the Validation, how can we achieve error message is always displayed

Tags: silverlight, validation

See picture first:
http://images.cnblogs.com/cnblogs_com/justinw/229829/o_validationask2.PNG

As shown: By default, error messages are moved to control the mouse when the display, the mouse away immediately disappeared.

I hope to achieve the effect: no matter how moving the mouse, the error message always shows, Silverlight Validation mechanism of this effect is supported by default, if not support, how to do? !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to edit the style for the control.

For example, the default template for a textbox has a "ValidationErrorElement" defined as a ToolTip that is only visible if the control has a validation error.  You chould change this to be a label instead.